# What is the modern day pronunciation of v in Latin as in van or as a w? And is the c soft as in cellar or hard as in cat?

Tags: classical-latin, new-latin, vulgar-latin, phonetics

What is the modern day pronunciation of v in Latin (as in van) or as a w sound?  And is the c soft as in cellar or hard as in cat?

Comment: What do you mean by "modern-day"? English-speaking lawyers reading legal terms, Catholic priests reading the liturgy, and classicists reading ancient poetry all pronounce these things differently.

Comment: To clarify: for many languages there's a "standard" pronunciation that native speakers consider the best. But there are no native Latin-speakers nowadays who could weigh in on something like that. I can give you my answer as a classicist (or tell you what a lawyer or a priest would say), but it would help if you clarify what particular usage you're asking about.

Comment: I agree with the comments above; however, I can add that modern-day enthusiasts generally try to conform to one of two standards.  In other settings, other pronunciations might be used, since different countries and regions inherited different pronunciation traditions.  For instance, an English-speaking choir singing a song in Latin composed by a German composer might pronounce the Latin according to the traditional German conventions.

Comment: A fairly fun discussion on here. https://youtu.be/_enn7NIo-S0